# A welcome message, that is pulled from a servlet that is configurable from the OSGi console

Tags: servlets, adobe, aem, sling

I am new to CQ5. I created a bundle that is configurable via the OSGi console. Now, I need the value that is configured on the console to be returned to my content page. I am not sure how to proceed with this. Looking for any tutorial or help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the configured value is available via an OSGi service, you can access that service from java code using an @Reference SCR annotation with a suitable build setup to generate the corresponding OSGi metadata. You can also access OSGi services from scripts, in JSP that's done using sling.getService(YourService.class) in a script where you have called  or its CQ equivalent.